# Ansible postgres_user become trouble

Tags: ansible, sudo, sudoers

Using the geerlingguy.postgresql Ansible role and can't get past the following error:

> TASK [geerlingguy.postgresql : Ensure PostgreSQL databases are present.] *******
>   failed: [database_host] (item={u'name': u'database_name'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"name": "database_name"}, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}

The task looks like so:

```
- name: Ensure PostgreSQL database is initialized. 
  command: "{{ postgresql_bin_path }}/initdb -D {{ postgresql_data_dir }}" 
  when: not pgdata_dir_version.stat.exists 
  become: yes 
  become_user: "{{ postgresql_user }}" 
   # See: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16048#issuecomment-229012509 
  vars: 
    ansible_ssh_pipelining: true
```

The value for `postgresql_user` is the OS default of postgres which is a valid user.  The `remote_user` I'm connecting with has full sudo with nopasswd and all other tasks before this (playbook runs with `become: true`) run fine.  I'm guessing this has something to do with switching to a non-privileged user but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: "*The remote_user I'm connecting with has full sudo with nopasswd*" - please show the settings from `/etc/sudoers` instead of describing their supposed effects.

Comment: devops ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following setting in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
devops  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

---

> <sup>from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984240/ansible-postgres-user-become-trouble/41990202#comment71157191_41984240):</sup>
>
> The `remote_user` I'm connecting with has full sudo with nopasswd
>
> > Please show the settings from `/etc/sudoers` instead of describing their supposed effects.
> >
> > > ```
> > > devops    ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
> > > ```

No, it doesn't have "*full sudo*" (whatever it means). You are allowing the `devops` user to run commands only as `root`, not as another user which you set in `{{ postgresql_user }}`.

Comment: Right you are, works great now, thanks!  I clearly misunderstood the sudoers format.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I did provide the {{ postgresql_user }} user sudo access to all commands (See line below) I still get the error "sudo: a password is required" sudoers line: "postgres ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"

Answer (score 0):

Simply You can use `--ask-sudo-pass` in ansible-playbook command. It will give you the password prompt for `devops` user. Adding entry to sudoers file can lead to the accident.